# htaccess mod_rewrite: Only one rule for all the URI's

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I read some tutorials about mod rewrite, but I can't find what I'm looking for. I want only one RewriteRule for all my URI's that is doing the following:

- I want that the '-' is replaced by '_'. So if i have example.com/page-hello is should be rewriten to example.com/page_hello
- Each url should be replaced with .php behind it. So if i have example.com/page, is should be rewriten to example.com/page.php

So my question is, how to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need separate rules for doing this. The first rule will rely on mod_rewrite looping until there are no dashes, the second will check if there are no dashes and it's not an existing file then append php to the end:

```
# Replace - with _
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)$ /$1_$2

# When there are no more -, check if the file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

These 2 rules will take a url like this:

> http://example.com/asd-fgh-jkl-/qwe-rty-uio

And rewrite the URI to:

> /asd_fgh_jkl_/qwe_rty_uio.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one "-" in what you want to rewrite this may be a problem. To solve this, use RewriteMap directive that executes an external "filter". See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap).
From the website, with emphasis on what you may look:

### External Rewriting Program

MapType: prg, MapSource: Unix filesystem path to valid regular file
Here the source is a program, not a map file. To create it *you can use a language of your choice*, but the result has to be an executable program (either object-code or a script with the magic cookie trick '#!/path/to/interpreter' as the first line).

This program is started once, when the Apache server is started, and then communicates with the rewriting engine via its stdin and stdout file-handles.

So my advice: make a very simple program in python that do a search/replace and call it with a RewriteMap directive, then add php to it.

Comment: Why is this method better than the rewriterules that Jon Lin posted?